# MS WS2012 R2 - Integrated NTP client / server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, ntp

Can WS2012 R2 be configured as a stratum-1 NTP clock source (client to NIST time servers) to which other internal hosts are synchronizing against ... hence NTP client and server functionality ?

From my research, NTP services seems to be "almost" non-existent on Windows servers in terms of available documentation and configuration and client verification commands.

Are admins forced to use 3rd party NTP clients on WS2012 and elect a different platform as their client to an Internet time server ?

I did come across a post on the Internet (on here in fact) for WS2008 R2 NTP client using w32tm but it was apparently causing more issues than benefits.

I am just trying to determine what the best practice is to synchronize my physical hosts running WS2012 R2.

Any constructive guidance would be much appreciated !

Thanks,
/ag

Comment: Is the server a domain controller or a member server of a domain?

Comment: BTW, whenever I read that w32tm as a time client is causing more issues, than benefits, I automatically assume the *admin* is a monkey, configuring computers by stuffing bananas in the floppy drive.

Answer (score 3):

Windows can not be configured as a stratum 1 NTP clock source explained under "Limitations": http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/WindowsTimeService